# Find the area of the region of the given curves

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area of the region between the curves
$y=x^{2013}$ and $y=x^{2014}$.

How do you define the upper and lower bound for this case? I found the point of intersection where $x=1$. So is it from $0$ to $1$? And when I tried to plot the graph on my graphic calculator it seems like I am getting a straight line. So should the upper bound be infinity for this case ?

Comment: No. $x^{2013}(x-1)=0 \Longrightarrow x=0,1$.

Comment: Yup forgot to type that. So any clue how to do this?

Comment: If you mean the area between the above curves, then it is $\int_0^1 \left(x^{2013}-x^{2014}\right) dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^{2013} > x^{2014} \quad \forall\ x\in(-1,1)$ the result will be
$$\int_0^1 x^{2013} - x^{2014} \ \ dx = \frac 1 {2014} - \frac 1 {2015}$$
It only seems to be a straight line, but it's not - it's just *almost* straight as in.
$$x^{2013} \approx 0 \approx x^{2014} \quad x \in (0,1)$$
With $"="$ at $x=0$ only.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of providing a little more detail about these curves, we can look at a couple of the values of the functions as they begin to depart from being *extremely* close to zero or one.  The binomial approximation gives us a pretty good idea of where either function equals 0.9:

$$ ( \ 1 - \xi \ )^{2013} \ \approx \ 1 \ - \ 2013 \xi \ = \ 0.9 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \xi \ = \ \frac{0.1}{2013} \ \approx \ 4.97 \cdot 10^{-5} \ \ , $$

so we find pretty nearly that $ \ (0.999950)^{2013} \ $ equals 0.9 .  A more precise result from a calculator is 0.9999477 , with the corresponding value of $ \ x \ $ for the function $ \ x^{2014} \ $ differing only in the *eighth* decimal place.  The binomial approximation, even extended to the quadratic term, is not adequate to estimate the values of $ \ x \ $ for these functions where they equal 0.1 ; instead, again using a calculator, we obtain $ \ (0.9988568)^{2013} \ \approx \ 0.1 \ $ , with the corresponding value of $ \ x \ $ for $ \ x^{2014} \ $ now differing only at the *seventh* decimal place.  So the "corner" where the curves turn from being practically "horizontal" to practically "vertical" is very "tight" indeed.

[image]

*The red curve represents $ \ x^{2013} \ $ , which is just above the blue curve for $ \ x^{2014} \ $ ; note the scale of the "turn" in the curves.*

It is a somewhat "popular" problem to ask students to find the area between the curves for $ \ y \ = \ x^m \ $ and $ \ y \ = \ x^n \ $ , with $ \ m \ $ and $ \ n \ $ being positive integers.  The curves will in all cases intersect at the origin and $ \ ( 1, 1 ) \ $ , so the general formula for the area is

$$ \int_0^1 \ x^m \ - \ x^n \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{m + 1} \ - \ \frac{1}{n + 1} \ = \ \frac{n \ - \ m}{(m+1) \ (n + 1)} \ \ , $$

which is positive for $ \ n \ > \ m \ $ , since the curve $ \ x^n \ $ will lie "below" that for $ \ x^m \ $ in the interval $ \ (0 \ , \ 1) \ $ .  For this problem, the area is then

$$\frac{1}{2014 \ \cdot \ 2015} \ \approx \ 2.46 \cdot 10^{-7} \ \ , $$

the thickness of which is actually *over-represented* in the graph above!

We have a similar situation in the interval $ \ (0 \ , \ 1) \ $ for the "root-functions" $ \ x^{1/m} \ $ and $ \ x^{1/n} \ $ , again with positive integers $ \ m \ $ and  $ \ n \ $ : the curves will exhibit a sharp turning behavior, now in the "upper-left" corner of the unit square with vertices at the origin and $  \ (1, 1) \ $ :

[image]

The curve in red for $ \ x^{1/2013} \ $ falls just below the curve in blue for $ \ x^{1/2014} \ $ ; again, notice the scale of the graph.

We can compute an analogous formula for the area between the curves of such functions:

$$ \int_0^1 \ x^{1/m} \ - \ x^{1/n} \ \ dx \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{(1/m) + 1} \ - \ \frac{1}{(1/n) + 1} $$

$$ =  \ \frac{m}{m + 1} \ - \ \frac{n}{n + 1}  = \ \frac{m \ - \ n}{(m+1) \ (n + 1)} \ \ , $$

which is here positive for $ \ m \ > \ n \ $ , since the curve $ \ x^{1/n} \ $ lies "below" that for $ \ x^{1/m} \ $ in this interval.